# Is there a way to ordinate numbers in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, numbers

I'm working on a table game called 'tombola' (I don't know the name in English).
The code gives me a list of numbers:

```
['22', '25', '75', '52', '70', '14', '5', '60', '81', '83', '72', '2', '36', '78', '10', '65', '43', '74', '51', '9', '29', '49', '24', '76', '23', '67', '35', '8', '85', '59', '18', '66', '38', '27', '19', '57', '77', '42', '84', '11', '46', '13', '89', '62', '7', '39', '32', '50', '86', '44', '64', '79', '54', '12', '68', '34', '15', '69', '71', '45', '20', '41', '82', '16', '1', '48', '37', '58', '61', '56', '53', '40', '80', '31', '87', '73', '90', '3', '88', '55', '30', '21', '4', '63', '26', '28', '33', '6', '17']
```

I need to ordinate these numbers in a crescent way and have an output that looks something like this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90']
```

Comment: What exactly does *"ordinate ... in a crescent way"* mean? Do you just mean *sort*? That doesn't seem like a fun game.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the scope of the game isn't ordinate the numbers

Comment: Then could you explain what exactly you *are* trying to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the actual game it's similar to bingo

Comment: I mean in the code. The phrase you've used does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you  have a list of strings and you want to sort them numerically. to do this you need to tell sort that it needs to sort each element as if it were an int.

```py
my_nums = ['22', '25', '75', '52', '70', '14', '5', '60', '81', '83', '72', '2', '36', '78', '10', '65', '43', '74', '51', '9', '29', '49', '24', '76', '23', '67', '35', '8', '85', '59', '18', '66', '38', '27', '19', '57', '77', '42', '84', '11', '46', '13', '89', '62', '7', '39', '32', '50', '86', '44', '64', '79', '54', '12', '68', '34', '15', '69', '71', '45', '20', '41', '82', '16', '1', '48', '37', '58', '61', '56', '53', '40', '80', '31', '87', '73', '90', '3', '88', '55', '30', '21', '4', '63', '26', '28', '33', '6', '17']
my_nums.sort(key=int)
print(my_nums)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90']
```